# Unable to create VM with Windows Server 2016 Core with Containers Tech Preview 5 in Azure Portal

Tags: windows, azure, containers

I am trying to create VM in Azure  portal with image "Windows Server 2016 Core with Containers Tech Preview 5".  Selected the Resource Manage and entered the name and password. On the Location drop down it shows the error message "The selected image is not valid for the specified location. Select a different location"  I tried with all the locations available in the drop down but no luck.  Same error message is shown.  Am I missing anything?

Regards

Luqman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had this error too. Be sure that the user you are logged in to the azure portal to create the VM is registered as a user of the subscription: In the portal, click "Subscriptions", select your subscription (i.e. "Visual Studio Enterprise") - new window opens - click on the access-symbol (icon with two users) in the upper right Corner - Window "Users" opens. Check if your user is listed, add, if not. 
Hope, that helps.

Regards, Rainer